# Matplotlib - logarithmic chart - adding extra text to chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a readable layout of a logarithmic chart, based on a pandas dataframe.
I have the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))
ax.clear()
ax.barh(mydataframe['Labels'], mydataframe['Values']
plt.xscale('log')
for i, (label, value) in enumerate(zip(mydataframe['Labels'], mydataframe['Values'])):
            ax.text(value + 1, i, f'{value:,.0f}', size=8, ha='left', va='center')
            ax.text(value + 20, i, f'({int(round(extraValue1)):d} -- {extraValue2:,.2f}%)', size=8, ha='left', va='center')
```

[image: Chart layout]

As you can see in the picture, my problem is the alignment of the second ax.text print on the chart. The first line of ax.text aligns perfectly the values at the end of each bar. But the second one, with the additional information I need to add, the alignment is messed up and overwrites the previous value, the more we go up to the bigger bars. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I have a feeling it's related to the chart being set with logarithmic scale.
The extravalue1 and 2 and also part of column of mydataframe, but for the simplicity of the code, I defined here the enumerate for only the main columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your x-axis is logarithmic, you'd want to use a *multiplicative* offset for your text, instead of an *additive* one. That is, try `value * 1.2` instead of `value + 20`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))
ax.clear()
ax.barh(mydataframe['Labels'], mydataframe['Values']
plt.xscale('log')
for i, (label, value) in enumerate(zip(mydataframe['Labels'], mydataframe['Values'])):
            ax.text(value * 1.05, i, f'{value:,.0f}', size=8, ha='left', va='center')
            ax.text(value * 1.2, i, f'({int(round(extraValue1)):d} -- {extraValue2:,.2f}%)', size=8, ha='left', va='center')
```

Please tune the `1.05` and `1.2` to fit your needs. The formatting could look at bit nicer if you combined both texts into one, but that's just taste.

Comment: Thank you! It still needs a bit of fixing because of the 3-4-5 digit values, but it does the job. I can take it from here

Answer (score 1):

To have a nice distance between the bar and the text, it is better to use the exact value for the `x` of the text and start the text with one or two spaces. So, using `ax.text(value, i, "  abc")` instead of `ax.text(value+20, i, "abc")`.  To have two texts, just concatenate them and place them in one go.

If you want text with multiple colors, and have them placed together with a gap adapting to the length of the first text, offset boxes can be used.

To have more space for the text, you can increase the x-margins, e.g. `ax.margins(x=0.2)`. At the same time you can decrease the y-margins, for which the defaults are a bit too large here.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import CSS4_COLORS
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredOffsetbox, TextArea, HPacker
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))
labels = ["".join(np.random.choice(list('abcdef'), 5)) for _ in range(20)]
values = np.sort(10 ** np.random.uniform(1, 5, 20))
ax.barh(labels, values, color=np.random.choice(list(CSS4_COLORS.keys()), 20))
ax.set_xscale('log')
for i, (label, value, extraValue1, extraValue2) in enumerate(
        zip(labels, values, *np.random.randint(100, 1000, (2, 20)))):
    xbox1 = TextArea(f'{value:,.0f}', textprops=dict(color="crimson", size=8, ha='left', va='baseline'))
    xbox2 = TextArea(f'({int(round(extraValue1)):d} -- {extraValue2:,.2f}%)',
                     textprops=dict(color="navy", size=8, ha='left', va='baseline'))
    xbox = HPacker(children=[xbox1, xbox2], align="baseline", pad=0, sep=5)
    anchored_xbox = AnchoredOffsetbox(loc="center left", child=xbox, pad=0.5, frameon=False, bbox_to_anchor=(value, i),
                                      borderpad=0, bbox_transform=ax.transData)
    ax.add_artist(anchored_xbox)
ax.margins(x=0.2, y=0.01)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to add some valuable information. The reason why I need to print various texts separately is because I want to color (or/ and format) that text differently for a better visual understanding.

Comment: I added a way to have a fixed distance between the different colored texts.

Comment: I implemented a simple suggestion of another user, using indenting based on value of each bar instead of a fixed indenting, since it's a logarithmic chart, and it worked. But I really like your solution as well. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even for the classic (non-log) chart it was a bit messed up, but I fixed with an indent based on value (if it's three or four digits)

```
if value<1000:
            indent = 80
        else:
            indent = 120
ax.text(value + 20, i, f'({int(round(extraValue1)):d} -- {extraValue2:,.2f}%)', size=8, ha='left', va='center')
```

The problem remains with log chart
[image: Classic chart]

Answer (score 0):

Just add the text you want to plot as one string not to:

```
for i, (label, value) in enumerate(zip(mydataframe['Labels'], mydataframe['Values'])):
    text = f'{value:,.0f}\t({int(round(extraValue1)):d} -- {extraValue2:,.2f}%)'
    ax.text(value + 1, i, text, size=8, ha='left', va='center')
```

Or am I missing something why you do not want to do this?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that, I did that at the beginning and it worked, but I want to color each additional information differently for a better visual understanding. That's why I need to print separately, unless there is other way.

Comment: You probably can do the coloring using Latex but I am not sure

Comment: Someone offered a solution. It works if I use an indent based on value, not fixed:  ax.text(value * indent, i, text, size=8, ha='left', va='center')